# Dúvida sobre c# int [-1,1]

Tags: c#, int

Bom pessoa, fiz um script onde ele troca de objetos com setactive em int ligado aos onclick botoes 1,2,3,4 e por ai vai

peço ajuda de vcs pra fazer a troca do int para -1,1 nos botoes onclick
a ideia seria assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class trocarobjetos : MonoBehaviour 
{
   private List<GameObject> modelos;
   private int selecaoIndex = 0;

   private void Start()
   {
      modelos= new List<GameObject>();
      foreach(Transform t in transform)
      {
         modelos.Add(t.gameObject);
         t.gameObject.SetActive(false);
      }
      modelos[selecaoIndex].SetActive(true);
   }
   public void SelecionarObjeto(int index)
   {
      if(index ==selecaoIndex)
         return;

      if(index < 0 || index >= modelos.Count)
         return;

      modelos[selecaoIndex].SetActive(false);
      selecaoIndex = index;
      modelos[selecaoIndex].SetActive(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: O código não funciona ? Dá erro ? O `-1` e `1` entra em que parte ? Não falta a tag `unity` ?

Comment: ele funciona perfeitamente, mais com int 1,2,3,4,etcs, queria fazer a troca pra -1 e 1 nos botoes

Comment: Mas o que é o `-1` e `1` nos botões ? E o que representa ?

Comment: Por exemplo, tem uma maneira de fazer a troca de gameobject usando o setactive com int -1 e 1, anterior e próximo, quando eu clico no botão interior ele volta o objeto que é -1. e o próxmo é o 1 que é adiantando os objetos...... deu pra entender?